# WPF C# Application Performance

Tags: c#, wpf, performance

We have a C# WPF application written in .Net 4.0, which some relatively simple data binding and grid functionality.

The styling invovles a few 'tweaks', including some hover colours and so on.

On 3 machines, out of a deployment covering 20, we are experiencing some very strange performance problems with the UI.

Effectively, after a reboot the application performs well, but after a certain (un-determined) amount of time, the UI becomes incredibly sluggish. For example, hovering the mouse over a button, and there will be a delay of up to a couple of seconds before the hover colour styling gets applied / rendered.

The machines have almost identical specifications. The graphics drivers have been updated, and the starndard setup is two NVidia Quadro 290 cards. Additoinally, we made a 'test' application containing ONLY some test UI components (including the Fluent Ribbon) and no code behind. The problem still occurs.

I have run the Windows Performance Suite to 'deep dive' the runtime WPF, and, very strangely, the UI returns to normal responsiveness if the option 'Disable Dirty Region Support' is ticked. My understanding is that, if anything, this should decrease performance further!!!

I'm at a loss of anything else to try here. A DotTrace performance analysis suggests most of the application time is spent in the PresentationFramework.dll.

**[EDIT]** All machines are Windows XP SP3.

**[EDIT]** It is possible that this occurs on all the machines and that the application is not usually allowed to run for long enough to present the problem. We are testing this now.

**[EDIT]** I should also point out that we are experimenting with the hotfix detailed [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2484841/en-us). It has been installed on a single machine for the moment, and I will update accordingly.

**[EDIT - 24 hours later]** So two machines have now been running the same code overnight. On my machine (which has never demonstrated the problem), after initial log in the application was very sluggish, but after less than a minute returned to normal. (I put that down to the machine clearly pulling things off the HDD). On the other machine (which usually demonstrates the problem), the applicaiton improved after a few seconds, but is still now sluggish in comparison to mine.

**[EDIT - 48 hours later]** On the test machine, the test application is now completely unresponsive (locked) after running for 48 hours. On the same machine, a lightweight 'shell' WPF application (containing a tab control, some buttons and a few panels and grids) is still running and perfectly responsive. So something in these more complex controls is causing this issue... which does indeed point back to (potentially) triggers and delegates that might be the root cause. I'll look to profile the application / controls again. In the mean time does anyone have any advice about how to ensure that the application 'cleans up' after itself at regular intervals? Because we are looking at third party controls here, so my options for editing them are limited!

Would appreciate any tips that can be provided!

Comment: Is it possible to provide code? some other SO'er would probably like to try this out as well.
How long is the least amount of time before issues appear?

Comment: I can provide code if necessary... but our test application at the moment literally involves using ONLY a Fluent Ribbon (dloadable from CodePlex), in and empty grid. There is no code behind apart from the obvious init call. I will of course provide this zipped up if it would make life easier.

Comment: Don't be expecting much from a prototype system. As a first step I'd check for delegates usage. Do you use the often?

Comment: We are trying to determine the minimum time now. I should be able to give you a more accurate answer soon. But at the moment, if I reboot the machine in question in the morning, the application works fine during the day, and by the time we check it the next day, this problem has presented itself.

Comment: @Dmitry What do you mean by a prototype system in this case? There are no delegates set up specifically, as we have no events / commands bound to the controls. (So nothing apart from what the framework sets up under the hood).

Comment: @Nick it must be something of an incremental nature - could you post some samples on how do you implement the visual effects - hovers, clicks etc. I presume you dom't use shaders do you?

Comment: @Nick I mean WPF. do you use Triggers much?

Comment: @Dmitry I agree r.e. incremental nature! We have used the Fluent Ribbon, and then the Infragistics XamRibbon and XamTileControl. I'll admit I haven't deep dived the source code for them, so can not answer for explicit styling etc. I'll take a look at the Fluent source code now.

Comment: @Dmitry I can confirm that the Fluent Ribbon seems to make pretty heavy use of Triggers.

Comment: Have you set up a deployment running only with controls, _without_ Fluent Ribbon?

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment We haven't tried that yet. But surely an empty app wouldn't add much value (!)... what would you recommend? A simple tab control or similar? We'd obviously need some way to see if it was actually 'performing'.

Comment: @Nick Yes, naturally you need some other controls, or something ...is XamRibbon part of Fluent Ribbon, you use any other third party elements, etc.? Basically, it seems that you haven't been able to rule Fluent Ribbon out, that's what I'm getting at.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment I hadn't pointed the finger at Fluent Ribbon as we weren't using that to start off with! XamRibbon is a ribbon control by Infragistics. The problem first started with their XamTile control. So we thought as that was animation heavy we would scrap it for the XamTile control. When the performance problem still cropped up, we swapped out to the Fluent Ribbon to try and rule the XamRibbon out!! Ok, I'll set up a more 'basic' application to test.

Comment: @Nick We had some isssues with the triggers in the past, since they deal with the events there's always a possibility of getting things pearshaped. Nice looking demo isn't the solid app yet. I'd suggest to use a moemory profiler. Does the memory consumotion grows rapidly - could you associate any memory hikes with specific user actions)?

Comment: @Dmitry Yeah, good point r.e. the triggers. And I certainly agree r.e. the demo. But I guess we had started to rule out specific 3rd parth controls as I've tried both the Infragistics side, as well as this Fluent Ribbon. The memory use stays stable. I'll check it again with a specific eye on user actions.

Comment: Are you adding event handlers dynamically (on button clicks, mouse over etc.) and not removing them correctly? The continual addition of handlers will eventually cause problems like this.

Comment: @ChrisF I am not explicitly, but it's difficult to answer for the third party controls. Infragistics are generally pretty good, but the code base is pretty large, even for the ribbon control. I will start to look through it. Have you got any suggestions for how to determine if this is happening at runtime?

Comment: No, sorry - other than debugging and/or code reviews.

Comment: @Nick what version of the Infragistics controls are you using?  Have you tested with the latest service release to see if the behavior changes.  Also since the behavior is different between two different machines, what is different between these machines?

Comment: @alhalama These applications are referencing the 11.1 set. I've downloaded 11.2, and will swap to that to see if it makes any difference. Keep in mind I've also tested with the Fluent Ribbon (non Infragistics) and seen similar restults, so can't accurately point the finger at a specific control! The machines are pretty much identical as far as I can see.

Comment: @Nick I would recommend installing the latest service release of 11.1 or when you install 11.2, install the service release as well.  Since the behavior is different on the two machines I would expect some difference in the machines to be a factor.

Answer (score 2):

try to render wpf in software mode.

in Loaded event:

```
HwndSource hwndSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
HwndTarget hwndTarget = hwndSource.CompositionTarget;
hwndTarget.RenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
```

Comment: I have tried this. I should point out that the issue persists across an application restart. So, if it's sluggish, I have tried reubuilding it with the SoftwareOnly flag, deploying it to the target machine, and it is still sluggish. Only a reboot grants an improvement!

Comment: Does Fluent Ribbon use layered windows?
see: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/seema/archive/2006/09/18/761314.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/seema/archive/2007/07/02/hw-acceleration-of-layered-windows-good-news.aspx

Comment: maybe playing with some registry settings:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970912.aspx

Comment: I've tried that registry setting. Basically a more forceful way of ensuring software rendering is happening. Not sure about the Fluent Ribbon and layered windows, I'll investigate. Upvoting as you've covered 2 good ways of checking software rendering :)

Answer (score 1):

Something to consider when comparing performance between developer and user machines is the time it takes to load the WPF assemblies.

On a dev machine you might already have visual studio running or have previously run other WPF apps and the assemblies should all have been loaded by the time you run your app.

On a user machine, perhaps freshly rebooted, the assemblies will be loaded when the app is started, making startup significantly slower. Depending on how the app is setup there might be additional assemblies loading when various features / pages are used for the first time.

I've found the [EQUATEC profiler](http://www.eqatec.com/Profiler/) to be useful in debugging these performance issues. Changing the profiling to "Full usual info" in the app options before building your project will profile down to the binding level.

Comment: I don't really believe this is to do with the startup time and preloaded assemblies. This is about long running in terms of application lifecycle. I have investigated various startup related issues as mentioned at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2007/10/10/improving-wpf-applications-startup-time.aspx

Comment: Additionally, I've run Procmon alongside the application and have noticed not file loading during normal operation (and whilst the UI is lagging). I will certainly give the EQUATEC profiler a go anyway though!

Comment: Thanks for the link, lots of stuff I'd been wondering about in there (e.g "placing Strong-Named Assemblies in the GAC" for faster startup)